# Creating geodatabase using QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, sqlite

I am using QGIS and am looking to get started on creating a geodatabase. I have point, line and polygon data. I want to arrange my database in categories that can store various point, line and polygon.  I currently just have a big collection of shape files which I know is not the way forwards!
The amount of processing I need to do with this data is limited, it is mostly just for viewing.  Sometimes I need to do basic processing such as buffer, and clip functions. In the future, I would be hoping that this database can also store photo data with my point data. 
Back in the day in school I learned ESRI geodatabase.  I have had some issues with the QGIS geopackage which is similar and am hoping to move to something different.

I am looking to move onto either an SQLite or PostGIS system but I'm just not sure where to start.  Once I decide which one to use I have found a lot of online resources where I can teach myself how to get it set up.  At this point, I am  just looking for a recommendation of which system to dive into.

The datasets that I work with are simple, however, they contain large amounts of data.

Comment: PostGIS is the geometry implementation, but the database is PostgreSQL. Unfortunately, GIS SE uses a Focused question/Best answer model; it is not a discussion list, so questions looking for "advice" are usually closed fairly quickly. If you had sufficient reputation, a post like this would be appropriate in [chat], but Chat is *underutilized* (folks seem to just want answers, not to hang out). In general, the way to learn open source tools is to find a tutorial, and run through it.

Comment: Use PostgreSQL/PostGIS - it is available in the cloud (amazon, digital ocean) if you want a quick startup to check it out... i highly recommend pgmodeler for diagramming your database... then you can spit out the design right into your postgresql database and begin loading/creating data...

Answer (score 1):

*Vince is right, as much as plenty people here would probably don't mind discussing this, the boards rules are rather clear about opinion seeking questions.*

*This is just to not leave you completely empty handed, trying to be as less biased as I can.*

Consider a main difference:

- PostgreSQL/PostGIS is a **full scale RDBMS**, and as thus dependend on **a running server** (that needs to be connected to from within your client software); you

  - have among the most scalable, powerful and performant GI suite at hand
  - are ready for excessive amounts of data
  - have access to countless specialized `ST` functions (*'Spatial Type'*)

  but you will need to invest in setup, maintenance and, most of all, knowledge (about plenty of other things than the actual GIS parts)
- A Geopackage **is a SQLite/SpatiaLite database at its core**, and as such a portable, **file based**, RDB/SQL powered spatial **data container**; you

  - can store and transport your data as you are used to
  - have access to most `ST` functions to process it

  but the underlying DB has performance  limits for very large datasets

Consider PostgreSQL/PostGIS as (part of) a backend *architecture*, and Geopackage/SQLite/SpatiaLite a powerful spatial *data file/container*.

Both can handle your requirements, and investing in PostgreSQL/PostGIS is absolutely worth it, but for localized (i.e. not network based) data storage (and relating to what you seem to need and want), I would probably recommend to give the Geopackage another go. If you have time to spare, go check out PostGIS.